# how can i run the debug command from windows 64x

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, cmd, system

I need to use the `debug` command in Windows 64x for learning purposes. When I type the command debug in the cmd, I get the following message:

```
'debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
```

As I understand from some previous posts that debug does not work in 64x systems. Is there any work around for this issue?

**EDIT:**
I am trying to write assembly code for learning. I am not allowed to use any other option for writing assembly code. I have to use DEBUG.

Comment: Download it and run it in DOSBox, if you insist on using `DEBUG`.

Comment: If you use Dosbox then you will need to get the debug command from a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Thanks. DOSBox was the suitable choice.

Answer (score 3):

debug.exe is not available in any of the 64 bit windows versions.  What are you trying to accomplish?  One option for you may be gnu debug - http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/

Comment: I want to write assembly code. It is for learning and I have to use DEBUG not any of the other available options.

Comment: You can try running a virtual machine with a 32 bit os.  +1 for the suggestion of dosbox above, it may work for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient thread, but others might have the same question.

In general to use legacy software, the CLEANEST way to do it is to use the build in Hyper-V. And then have PC-DOS 3.30 (or any suitable 16 or 32 bit OS) on that.

Make sure to use a DYNAMIC disk (vhdx). This allows the disk to be mounted in Windows simply by clicking the vhdx (when not in use by Hyper-V - no sharing), so this allows for simple transfers, without complex net-setup.

There are other alternatives such as DOSBOX, though to my experience their emulation have some bugs (e.g. on the ancient FCB-system - older than file-handles)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very long answer, but I just saw your post now. Use the vDosPlus (http://www.vdosplus.org/) or vDos (https://www.vdos.info/) software to run 16-bit (MS-DOS) programs on Windows 64-bit.